# Is there a way to inject a widget UNDER the Navigator with GoRouter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

In the `MaterialApp` constructor, I am injecting a widget in the `builder` method to handle push notifications. To process foreground notification, I would like to use this widget to show a notification bar (using `another_flushbar`) but I need a Navigator in the context for that, and `MaterialApp`'s builder injects above the Navigator, so when I try to using it to push my notification bar, there is no Navigator accessible via the context.

Of course, I could wrap every screen of my app with my notification-handling widget, but it defeats the purpose. I want a widget that is always on screen when the app is running, and that can show my notification bar, wherever I am in my app.

Any idea how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it, while still using `MaterialApp`'s `builder` to inject my `NotificationHandler` widget ABOVE the `Navigator`.

1. My `NotificationHandler` widget accepts a `GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey` property
2. When I initialize my `NotificationHandler` widget inside of `MaterialApp`'s `builder`, I pass it `GoRouter.routerDelegate.navigatorKey`
3. Inside of `NotificationHandler`, when I need a context with a Navigator above it, I use `navigatorKey.currentContext` insted of my local widget context.

This solution was inspired by [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103009).